# Difficulty accessing property on another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I feel I must be going about this the wrong way and there is probably a very simple solution that I cant seem to find. In ClassA.h I have:

```
@property (strong, retain) NSManagedObject *form;
```

In ClassB I have tried:

```
#import "ClassA"

@interface ClassB  ()
{
    ClassA *classA;
}
```

Then in viewDidLoad I have:

```
NSLog(@"form::%@", classA.form);
```

but its nil everytime even though when Im on classA (its a viewcontroller) it definitely has a value.

**EDIT:**

So I followed the example given by BlackRider 
classA

```
 MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
    sharedManager.someProperty = self.form;
```

classB

```
MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];

                    NSLog(@"globalform::%@", sharedManager.someProperty);
```

and Im still getting null value in the log print.

Comment: That is because you probably have 2 instances of ClassA.

Comment: If you don't set it first, it is nil

Comment: Show us the code that initializes `classA` to some existing instance of `ClassA`.

Comment: @robmayoff Im sorry but what do you mean the code that initializes classA. Its a viewcontroller for a storyboard view

Comment: @BlackRider well how do I get just one then?

Comment: You need to actually set your `ClassA` variable in your `ClassB` view controller to something. If you are using storyboards the easiest way to set things between view controllers is in `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: @BluGeni see my answer below.

Comment: `ClassA *classAInstance = [[ClassA alloc] init];` then you can `NSLog(@"form::%@", classAInstance.form);` I would possibly recommend looking at singletons in objective-c

Comment: @Popeye I have never used a singleton before but Im not against it. How would it look?

Comment: A good example of one is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-should-my-objective-c-singleton-look-like answered by `Ben Hoffstein`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using my appDelegate and using it to store a "global" variable.

Answer (score 1):

You really should make ClassA a property of ClassB using `@property (nonatomic, strong) ClassA *classA;` in the interface, this will generate a setter and getter for you. Using a plain C variable like you have done means you can only access it using `->` pointer indirection, and it will be protected by default. Mostly people use these kinds of variables in a class extension in their implementation, but properties on their interface.

Wherever you instantiate your `ClassB` class, set its classA property using `classB.classA = self;`

For example:

```
- (void)loadMyForm {
    ClassB *classB = [ClassB alloc] init];
    classB.classA = self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use a storyboard (and probably segues) here's what you can do:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get a reference to the destination view controller
    if([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[ClassA class]]) {
        ClassA *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // now you can access vc.form
    }
}
```

Comment: ClassA is a view controller for a storyboard but ClassB is not.

Comment: In this case it gets a little more clunky. Cause it's in the method above that you can first access the view controller instance.

Like someone else suggested in a comment, consider making the `form` object a singleton.

Comment: How would a singleton look for me?

Comment: I followed this code example but am still getting a null value in classB Refer to my updated question for the code I used

Comment: Do not learn about singletons until you figure out how basic properties work.  You will end up with tons of pointless singletons.

Comment: I agree with @AaronBrager.